# How to force "echo *" to print items on separate lines in Unix?

Tags: shell, unix, echo

Is `*` some variable?
When I do `echo *` it lists my working directory on one line. How can I force this command to print each item on a separate line?

Comment: Beware the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The answers you've gotten here are valid and working ways of getting filenames on separate lines, but they're not good starting points for doing anything more with those files (if you intend to do something more with this list, you should ask about your overarching problem instead).

Comment: no concrete aim, it was just theoretical question, hardcore way I did it was using find with -maxdepth 1 then using sed to get rid of prefix

Comment: oddly enough i was looking exactly for a way to list a dir on one line :D

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to ditch the non-portable `echo` completely in favor of `printf`:

```
 printf '%s\n' *
```

However, the printf (and echo) way have a drawback: if the command is not a built-in and there are a lot of files, expanding `*` may overflow the maximum length of a command line (which you can query with `getconf ARG_MAX`). Thus, 
to list files, use the command that was designed for the job:

```
ls -1
```

which doesn't have this problem; or even

```
find .
```

if you need recursive lists.

Comment: Nicely done, but note that `getconf ARG_MAX` typically does NOT come into play here, because `printf` is a _builtin_ in all major POSIX-like shells, i.e., `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`; `getconf ARG_MAX` only applies when invoking _external utilities_. You can verify this with `printf %s "$(printf "%$(getconf ARG_MAX)s")"`, which _should_ break if the limit _did_ apply, but does _not_. Contrast with `/usr/bin/printf %s "$(printf "%$(getconf ARG_MAX)s")"`, which _does_ break.

Comment: Jens, please qualify the `ARG_MAX` information in your answer to say that it only applies when the _external utility_ versions of `printf` or `echo` are invoked, as opposed to the shell builtins of the same name.

Answer (score 4):

`*` - is not a variable. It's called *globbing* or *filename expansion* - bash itself expands wildcards and replaces them with filenames. So `*` will be replaced with list of all non-hidden items from current directory.

If you just want to print the list of files in the current directory - you can use `ls`. Also, if you wish to use `echo` - you can do it like this:

```
for item in *
do
    echo $item
done
```

it will print each item on a separate line.

More details about bash globbing you can find here:
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html

Answer (score 3):

The `echo` command by itself cannot do this.

If you want to print each file name on its own line, I guess there's something you want to do with the output other than just reading it. If you tell us what that is, we can probably help you more effectively.

To list the files in the current directory, you can use `ls -1`. The `ls` command also prints one name per line if its output is redirected to a file or through a pipe.

Another alternative is the `printf` command. If you give it more arguments than are specified in the format string, it will cycle through the format, so this:

```
printf '%s\n' *
```

will also print one file name per line.